# Migrate classic ASP with COM+ to Azure Cloud and DLLs

Tags: c#, azure, iis, asp-classic, com+

I have a classic ASP web application and want to host it in the Azure Cloud (our own companies private Azure Pack).

This app uses COM+ objects for things like data access to databases and some other small utilities.

It is pretty easy to host ASP pages on Azure (it just needs an IIS container) but it seems COM+ objects are not supported.

This is all a stop-gap until this application get's retired, but moving to Azure would be beneficial as we are moving everything to Azure.

How can I continue to support the data access components and other COM+ utilities called by the app?

I am open minded to:

1. Decompile them, figure out what they do, and rebuild them in .NET
2. Host them in some kind of container assembly (like Interop of some kind)
3. Put them in a 'bin' folder and call them from there (told this prob won't work)

Comment: "Don't hang up the phone!" Lol. At least you know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure COM Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039950/azure-com-objects)

Comment: Windows containers still support ASP and COM+, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/overview/containers/ So you should move such apps onto them and then deploy to Azure. Though truly, you should rewrite such with modern technologies like ASP.NET Core as a whole.

Answer (score -2):

#### Use Azure WebRoles

You actually can do this in the older Azure WebRole PaaS. It's a very thin platform over a windows VM, so there is a lot you can do with WebRoles that you can't do in AppServices or other newer PaaS in Azure. WebRoles allow you to define some installation hooks that you can use to register your COM+ components or even install other complex dependencies. [See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16040753/947986) for more details.

You can even enable Remote Desktop for WebRoles and connect directly to your instance. This is really helpful in troubleshooting any issues with your setup, but it is important to capture all changes that you need to make in your installation scripts, as certain Azure-managed events will cause your WebRole to be re-imaged, in which case you will lose any customizations made through RDP that are not part of your install hooks.

Comment: You already point to a duplicate, why not just flag it as such and move on?