# Unable to use ASPPDF on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been having trouble being able to use any of the functionality of ASPPDF on a web app I publish to Azure. When running the website locally through Visual Studio, the website behaves as expected, and I can use any of the methods in the ASPPDF library. However, when I publish to Azure and test the website I get this error: "Retrieving the COM class factory failed due to the following error: 80040154."

This error is documented here: http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=ps071016166.

The Azure App Service I am publishing to is 64-bit as well as the project I am working on is configured for 64-bit. The libraries from ASPPDF are also 64-bit. Making any one of these 32-bit is not an option since the App Service must be 64-bit.

I have already viewed this: [AspPDF and AspJPEG on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981830/asppdf-and-aspjpeg-on-windows-azure). And I don't see how I can apply that solution to an App Service in Azure.

Has anyone had any success using ASPPdf on an Azure App Service?

Comment: There are several related questions (and answers) here, but TL;DR Web Apps (App Services) are sandboxed; you cannot do certain things, like working with COM/ActiveX/GDI. You'd need to run this in a VM.

Comment: fyi [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563426/debenu-pdf-works-on-localhost-fails-on-azure) and answer provides more detail.